# Code-sense in embedXcode doesn't hightlight syntax for the library I've included

Tags: c++, xcode, arduino, syntax-highlighting, fastled

Code-sense mostly works-- all of the core Arduino types are hightlighted properly. But no types 
referencing the FastLED library are.

[image: code-sense not working]

My code compiles fine. And, syntax is hightlighted properly in FastLED.h

[image: code-sense working]

How can I make use of code-sense in xCode for Arduino libraries?

At the top of my .ino file, I do this

```
// Core library for code-sense
#include "Wiring.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

// Include application, user and local libraries
#include "LocalLibrary.h"
#include "FastLED.h"
```

I am running XCode 5.1 on OSX 10.9.2 with embedXcode+ (professional) release 136. I checked out the FastLED_2.1 branch, as master does not support Teensy 3.1, the board I am using.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**  It appears that NO libraries listed in USER_LIBS_LIST confer the benefits to code-sense to your main ino file. However, once I moved the FastLED from

```
/Users/justin/Documents/Arduino/Libraries
```

to

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries
```

and restarted XCode, everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the table for libraries reached an overflow.

> WARNING   Overflow reached

Comment: Why would this happen?